# got error in jasper report in openbravo

Tags: jasper-reports, tomcat8, openbravo

i have follow the step provide by [openbrvao wiki](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_create_a_Report)and try to develope  jasper report.

and for that

my process defination window display like below image.
[image]

and report defination tab display like below.[image]

and also make menu window that display like below image.
[image]

and when we try to open that report we get that the error **" string index out of range 3"**

so please help me to solve that problem or suggest some tutorial.

i try to my best to solve this problem but i don't able to solve this so pls help me to solve out this problem.

error display like below image when we try to develope image.
[image]
i also added my jasper reprt that display like below image[image]
and i have also added my product.jrxml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
<!-- 2016-03-03T14:25:56 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="productlist" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Error" uuid="1bdd34fb-ffa2-40ce-9089-1b93045bd142">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT m_product_id , name FROM m_product limit 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="m_product_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="198" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="673ddd4e-fce0-4c61-9e5d-5fd1eb4768f5"/>
                <text><![CDATA[m_product_id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="438" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c5932b0d-78ff-4504-85e7-e673d43145dc"/>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="198" y="44" width="100" height="30" uuid="be5747bd-3739-4a3f-ab91-d85facbf3719"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{m_product_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="438" y="44" width="100" height="30" uuid="09ffb3ae-5230-4b91-aa4a-4a5bd2ae7ad3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**error log for this error :-**

[http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.openbravo.erpCommon.utility.HttpsUtils - Unable to reach butler.openbravo.com
2016-03-04 06:25:12,436 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet - String index out of range: 3
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.filter(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2780)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1253)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Kit.classOrNull(Kit.java:92)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:159)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:114)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaTopPackage.init(NativeJavaTopPackage.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.buildClassCtor(ScriptableObject.java:1030)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.LazilyLoadedCtor.buildValue(LazilyLoadedCtor.java:110)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.LazilyLoadedCtor.init(LazilyLoadedCtor.java:89)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.sealObject(ScriptableObject.java:1567)
    at com.googlecode.jslint4java.JSLint.(JSLint.java:113)

Comment: share your output/error log and jrxml file.

Comment: @ManiDeep i added my jrxml file screen short

Comment: not your screenshot, need the code in jrxml. use `button: source` at the bottom left beside Preview, to get the `jrxml code`. also your console.log error

Comment: ya i know that now i uploaded the code @ManiDeep

Comment: @ManiDeep pls help me to solve out this.

Comment: I dont see any issue in your jrxml code, i already said you to include console/log errors.

Comment: i don't get any console or log error but getting msg " error string indexout of bound : 3 " @ManiDeep

Comment: Its better if you manage to find the log..., in jrxml there is nothing indexOutOfBound... except old oracle driver that when you try to getString from int, throws strange exceptions..... you are sure that both of your column types are varchar (string), m_product_id seems like an java.lang.Integer or Long

Comment: @PetterFriberg i have use postgre sql and both column are string

Comment: Then the error is else where, what other code do you have, search for logs ecc..

Comment: @PetterFriberg sorry but i don't get any  error log for this.

Comment: I'm sorry to since as is this question is missing info to answer [mcve]. You are sure that openbravo does not log somewhere, maybe enable it... ecc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105261/discussion-between-kap-and-petter-friberg).

Comment: @ManiDeep pls help to debug actionhandlerclass file

Comment: @ManiDeep i m getting below error                                                                                [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.openbravo.erpCommon.utility.HttpsUtils - Unable to reach butler.openbravo.com
 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] ERROR org.openbravo.client.kernel.KernelServlet - String index out of range: 3
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.filter(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2780)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass

Comment: @ManiDeep  thank you for your help i solved the my problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thank you for your help to i solved the my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the my answer that not my fault but i use the ***tomcat version 8.0.32*** and that have bug so for solve this **i have degrade my tomcat version from 8.0.32 to 8.0.26 that solve my problem.**

above error is a bug in [tomcat](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58999) itself.
so go through link to solve this.

Comment: @ManiDeep thank you for your help to i solved the my problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thank you for your help to i solved the my problem.